# Best database type and schema to search by attributes

Tags: mysql, mongodb, search, attributes, database

I know that this question may not have an easy answer or at least many possible correct ones.

I am developing a weather web app to search cities by summary, temperature, humidity, precipitation, wind speed, visibility, pressure and some other weather indicators. I will also include the weather station set up that, for making things easier, let’s consider it is unique in every city. I would also like to include some city data such as: population, afforestation index as well as latitude, longitude.

Continent, Country and Region will also be needed.

Weather station will include the model number of every sensor installed in it.

There will be around 5.000 cities.

Most used query will be to search the cities by a temperature, humidity, precipitation, wind speed, visibility and pressure range as well as filtering by population, etc. and weather station sensor model name.

A query would look like:

- summary = “Clear”
- and temperature > 6 and temperature < 10
- and pressure > 900 and pressure <1000
- and visibility > 5 and visibility < 7
- and  humidity > 0.60 and humidity < 0.90
- and population is > 20.000
- and afforestation index is > 3
- and country = France
- and “sensor1” = “string”

**The question is:** What database type and schema fit the best my search needs regarding to performance? As you can see I need to search by attributes and not by the city name itself. I am completely **free to use Relational or NoSQL database** rather that I would like to use an asynchronous system.

I don’t know if a NoSQL db like MongoDB is intended to be used like this, if this is the case, would this schema be fast enough? I am worried as everything is nested and indexes can be huge.

```
"continents": 
[
    {
        "name": "Europe",
        "countries": 
        [
            {
                "name": "France",
                "regions": 
                [
                    {
                        "name": "Île-de-France"
                        "cities": 
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "Paris",
                                "coordinates": {"lat": 48.856614, "lon": 2.352222},
                                "summary":"Clear",
                                "temperature": 9.4,
                                "pressure": 976,
                                "visibility" : 6.8,
                                "humidity" : 0.84,
                                "afforestation": 6,
                                "population": 2249975,
                                ...
                                "weather_station": {
                                    "name": "name",
                                    "sensor 1": "string",
                                    "sensor 2": "string",
                                    "sensor 3": "string",
                                    "sensor 4": "string",
                                }
                            },
                            ...
                        ]
                    },
                    ...
                ]                   
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

I guess this use case has been developed in many other apps that require a search by element attributes.

Oh! I forgot to say that I am using Python and Tornado web framework.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have You Looked At Neo4j ,its a Graph database ,which work better in a attribute enviroment

Comment: Another possibility is to flatten  your data by separating the cities into a separate collection and adding a Link to a Region Collection ,or invert Your data so that Region data is a nested section

Answer (score 0):

The Following Schema May be what you are Looking for.

Note that in document DB's you will need to denormalize your data slightly to match the way its accessed the most

this would be 1 row in a City Collection

```
{
    "City": "Paris",
    "coordinates": {"lat": 48.856614, "lon": 2.352222},
    "summary":"Clear",
    "temperature": 9.4,
    "pressure": 976,
    "visibility" : 6.8,
    "humidity" : 0.84,
    "afforestation": 6,
    "population": 2249975,
    ...
    "weather_station": {
        "name": "name",
        "sensor 1": "string",
        "sensor 2": "string",
        "sensor 3": "string",
        "sensor 4": "string",
    }
    "region": "Île-de-France",
    "country":"France",
    "continent":"Europe"
}
```

Comment: that is spot on. note that mongo has an awesome async driver called motor that fits perfectly with tornado.

Comment: Many thanks for the schema Tony Stark (I always wanted to say that)!

In case regions, countries and continents contain more data than its name, would it be okay, in terms of search performance, to create three additional collections (region, countries and continents) and link them to the city collection? Is this good for search performance? Is this what you suggested in your comment above?

Comment: :) Yes you can, this was my initial suggestion in the comments, down side of this is: you will need to pre-search your Id fields from their own collection to find their Id's in the city data as there is no joins in document DB's

Answer (score 0):

5000 rows in one table?  About 20 metrics?  No "history"?

Make a single table with 5000 rows and 20 columns.  No INDEXes other than the minimal PRIMARY KEY for UPDATEing a row when a weather station reports in. Build a SELECT from the desired conditions, then let to optimizer do a full table scan.

Everything will stay in RAM, and the SELECTs will be "brute force".  It should take only a few milliseconds.  (I ran a similar SELECT on a 2.7M-row table; it took 1.3 seconds.)

If you are keeping history, then we need to talk further.

Comment: Hi Rick, Do you mean in a relational database?

Comment: Yes.  I am thinking in terms of MySQL RDBMS.  I'm not (at the moment) using anything "relational", merely using it as a storage and search mechanism.  If it is only 500*20 metrics, you may as well load them into arrays in your programming language, and not use any kind of database.  But then you have to simulate `and visibility > 5 and visibility < 7 and ...`